# Java RMI remote call

Tags: java, serialization, call, rmi

I have a doubt in a list of exercises on Java. I have not coded the exercise. If you can help me.

Question:

The diagram below represents a client / server application in Java RMI. Interfaces A and C are remote and class B is serializable. 
Diagram : http://oi62.tinypic.com/149s26r.jpg

The codes of methods f, g and h are as follows:

```
void f () {System.out.println ("A :: f"); } 
void g () {System.out.println ("B :: g"); a.f(); } 
void h (B b) {System.out.println ("C :: h"); b.g (); }
```

What is printed by this program and where (ie at the server or client) when making the following call to the client:

```
s.h (b)
```

My answer: 
It will be printed

```
 C::h   (Server)
 B::g   (Client)
 A::f   (Client)
```

Thank you

Comment: Why do you think anything will get printed at the client?

Comment: Because b.g() will call client methods?

Comment: How will it do that? `B` isn't a remote object.